# Welcome screen after a user has logged in | Angular 1.5 and Ionic V1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-routing

I want to display an HTML file when a user has logged in. Right now we have a slideshow that is presented to the user after logging in, but after it, I want to display another view.

I jumped on this project although I'm new to Angular and Ionic, I assume this is how we render out the slideshow:

In our controller, we have an `IntroCtrl` which operates the logic behind the slideshow. So, do I need to create another controller to display my view afterwards?

```
.controller('IntroCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $localStorage, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $ionicScrollDelegate, $stateParams) {

$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function (e) {
    $ionicScrollDelegate.resize()
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(0, 1)
})
$scope.email = $stateParams.email
$scope.startApp = function () {
    $localStorage.hasViewedSlideBox
    $state.transitionTo('tab.dash')
}

$scope.next = function () {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
}
```

})

I found this in our `app.js` and this file contains `$stateProvider`, `$urlRouterProvider`, `$ionicConfigProvider`.
At the bottom I found a lot of these:

```
.state('login', {
url: '/login',
cache: false,
templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
controller: 'LoginCtrl'
```

})

Therefore I assume I should create a new one containing the templateUrl and controller of my view? I read online that these `.state` has to do with Angular routing, but I can be wrong.

However, I would be really happy if anyone could guide me here.
Like I said, I want to display a new view after the slideshow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest create a new html and design your "`afterLogin`" html and copy your `state`(to which you will be redirected after login), comment it out and change the `templateUrl` to your new html file.
That should do all what you want.
You don't need your `IntroCrl` in the new file because it will only run a slideshow which is not present.
But you should insert

```
$scope.startApp = function () {
    $localStorage.hasViewedSlideBox
    $state.transitionTo('tab.dash')
}
```

into your new controller.

If you don't have a route to which you are redirected after login, you have to provide more code, so we can dive more deep into it

Comment: Hey!

I didn't realise that `$state.transitionTo('tab.dash')` transitions to another `.state`. And all of the states are being created in my `app.js` file.

But where do you want me to insert that piece of code that you wrote?

Comment: I thought startApp will actually start the app and stop the slider